# How to catch the exception when Node worker exits with code 3

Tags: node.js

I have an app who instantiates a nodejs cluster/workers to execute some routines.

Most of the time everything works fine, but sometimes i am getting some weird error logs.

How could i identify the cause of the error if the root exception is not logged?

The only logs that i get are like below:

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe[3708]: src\node.cc:1453: Assertion `(env_->execution_async_id()) == (0)' failed.
 1: node::DecodeWrite
 2: node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope
 3: node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope
 4: node::MakeCallback
 5: node::Start
 6: uv_run
 7: node::FreeEnvironment
 8: node::FreeEnvironment
 9: node::Start
10: lh_node_usage_stats_bio
11: BaseThreadInitThunk
12: RtlUserThreadStart
worker 3708 died with code 3
Worker 11872 started
Worker 11872 is running on port 10000
FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal.
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::V8::ToLocalEmpty
 3: v8::internal::StackGuard::ArchiveSpacePerThread
 4: v8::internal::StackGuard::ArchiveSpacePerThread
 5: node::Start
 6: v8::internal::AsmJsScanner::IsNumberStart
 7: 00000246365843C1
worker 10952 died with code 3
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe[8512]: src\node.cc:1453: Assertion `(env_->execution_async_id()) == (0)' failed.
 1: node::DecodeWrite
 2: node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope
 3: node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope
 4: node::MakeCallback
 5: node::Start
 6: uv_run
 7: node::FreeEnvironment
 8: node::FreeEnvironment
 9: node::Start
10: lh_node_usage_stats_bio
11: BaseThreadInitThunk
12: RtlUserThreadStart
worker 8512 died with code 3
```

Comment: did you tried to put Try Catch in your code ?

Comment: Try catch does not seem to work. Im not sure why. Any other suggestion?

Comment: This is the only operation to catch exceptions, whatever the technology that you are using

Comment: What about listeners on the process events? I already have a try/catch that does not log the err stack i am guessing its because the process dies, but im not sure.